# why the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 doesn't work on static routing?

Tags: networking, routing

When I set a static route for an IP address why does these commands work:

```
route -p ADD 65.182.174.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1

route -p ADD 65.182.174.11 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
```

And this command doesn't work

```
route -p ADD 65.182.174.11 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

I don't understand the subnet mask that much. But what I understood was "A subnet mask is used to divide an IP address into two parts. One part identifies the host (computer), the other part identifies the network to which it belongs."

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Your Router is for one IP address.  255.255.255.255.0 is for a whole subnet. 255.255.255.255.255 is for that one single IP address.

Comment: Got it Thanks for your answer

Comment: You might want to also look up [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Answer (score 0):

When configuring routes, the mask is used to determine *which address bits to compare* when the system checks which routes match a given address. (Note that the route netmask isn't always the same as the destination's subnet mask – it's about which addresses *you* want to include in the route, so it could specify a single host, half a subnet, 16 subnets at once, etc.)

For example, when you use `65.182.174.0 mask 255.255.255.0`, that actually means you want the route to match `65.182.174.<any>` – because the netmask only has first 24 bits set to '1', it means only the first 24 address bits are compared and the rest is ignored.

So in theory, the system *could* accept `65.182.174.11 mask 255.255.255.0` and it would still mean exactly the same thing: the `.11` would be ignored and only `65.182.174.` would be used for route matching.

Rejecting such entries is usually deliberate, since it can catch certain mistakes – e.g. in this example, the operator could have mistyped the netmask (entering `.0` when they meant `.255`) and accidentally routed a whole subnet when they just wanted to route a single host. So many systems insist that the network address must have all 'host' bits set to 0 because it more accurately specifies what you want to route.

Comment: Thanks! this helped alot :)